# view stdout and stderr of all the lines of my scripts in my terminal when the script has both sudo and non-sudo commands

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am running the following script as sudo.

```
#!/bin/bash

whoami
echo $USER ~
sudo -u blueray bash <<"DOF"
whoami
echo $USER ~
DOF

echo "Running script as user $(whoami)"
sudo -u blueray echo "Running script as user $(whoami)"
sudo -u blueray bash -c 'echo "Running script as user $(whoami)"'
```

Getting the following result:

```
% sudo bash test.sh 2>&1 | tee --append /tmp/log.txt
root
root /root
blueray
blueray /home/blueray
Running script as user root
Running script as user root
Running script as user blueray
```

My issue is , I am trying to run a script which has sudo and non-sudo commands in it.

The [suggestions](https://askubuntu.com/a/425990/598062) say that using `sudo -u username command` in script will run the lines as specified user. But my findings is showing otherwise. In my case only `sudo -u blueray bash -c` works. But subshell and `bash -c` works differently.

```
% var=value
% bash -c 'echo $var'
% (echo $var)
value
```

So not understanding if this is what I really want.

Moreover, I want to run my script sequentially and not in parallel. Not sure if `sudo -u blueray bash -c` will open a different shell and run those in parallel or not.

In summary, I want to **view stdout and stderr of all the lines of my scripts in my terminal**. I want to **run the script as sudo except specific lines**. I want to **run the script sequentially and not in parallel**.

My script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt update
apt upgrade -y
apt install -y git zsh zsh-autosuggestions zsh-syntax-highlighting python3 python-is-python3 python3-pip mdadm
chsh -s $(which zsh)

mdadm --assemble --scan

tee -a /etc/fstab << END
LABEL=8TBRaid0 /media/blueray/8TBRaid0  ext4  nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show  0  2
LABEL=WDPurple8TB /media/blueray/WDPurple8TB  ext4  nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show  0  2
LABEL=WDPurple6TB /media/blueray/WDPurple6TB  ext4  nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show  0  2
END

curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main"| tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list

add-apt-repository -y ppa:christian-boxdoerfer/fsearch-stable

apt update
apt upgrade -y

apt install -y foliate brave-browser

curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/rootless | sh
systemctl --user start docker.service
systemctl --user enable docker.service
loginctl enable-linger blueray

wget -O firefox.tar.bz2 "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest-ssl&os=linux64&lang=en-US"
tar xjf firefox.tar.bz2
apt remove firefox
mv firefox/ /opt/firefox
rm firefox.tar.bz2
ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
desktop-file-install /media/blueray/WDPurple6TB/_Working/_NotesFiltered/linux-mint/supporting-files/Firefox.desktop

pip install yapf
```

Comment: An alternative is to run the script as the normal user (without sudo), and use sudo in the script only for the tasks that need sudo. I use that method, and it works for me. Let me know, if you want an example of such scripting.

Comment: @sudodus yes that will be great but I do not want the script to ask for password every time.

Comment: Are you aware that in `sudo -u blueray echo "Running script as user $(whoami)"` that `$(whoami)` is expanded *before* `sudo` runs?

Comment: See [this link](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info/). The fixes at the beginning [of the main part of the script] are not necessary, but makes the script more noob-proof. Actually, most Linux systems let you (and scripts) use sudo within a grace period of 10-15 minutes without password after the first time you enter the password.

Comment: Please explain what the final objective here is. As far as I can tell, all the commands in your script should be run as root with the exception of the `chsh` command, unless you are trying to change root's default shell. Is there something there that you do not want to run as root?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski maybe this is why it way giving unexpected behavior. So, can I safely use `sudo -u blueray echo "Running script as user $(whoami)"`

Comment: @terdon I do not want root for `pip install yapf`, `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/rootless | sh`, `systemctl --user start docker.service`, `systemctl --user enable docker.service`, `wget -O firefox.tar.bz ....` etc.

Comment: The following two commands show different users (if run by another user, not 'blueray'), `sudo -u blueray echo "Running script as user $(whoami)"`; `sudo -u blueray bash -c 'echo "Running script as user $(whoami)"'`

Comment: @sudodus so when it encounters the sudo for the first time, it will ask for the password, then for next 15 minutes, it will not. This is a good idea.

Comment: "Can I safely use… ?" – It depends on what you want (and what you mean by "safely"). My impression was you were surprised the next-to-last line of your first script had given you `root`, not `blueray`; and this was(?) a part of the problem.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes this was the main problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the output, but that's very understandable, it is confusing. Specifically, this line:

```
sudo -u blueray echo "Running script as user $(whoami)"
```

That will run `echo` as the user `blueray`, BUT, everything in the command is expanded before echo is launched. That's just how the shell works and that's why `echo $var` will print the value of the variable and not just the string `$var`. In other words, when you run the command above, what happens is:

1. The shell expands `$(whoami)` to the output of the `whoami` command, which is `root`.
2. The shell calls `echo` passing it the expanded value.

So what you are actually running is

```
sudo -u blueray echo "Running script as user root"
```

To get the behavior you were expecting, you need to call a new shell and tell it to run the command, using single quotes instead of double quotes because single quotes block expansion:

```
sudo -u blueray bash -c 'echo "Running script as user $(whoami)"'
```

To illustrate:

```
$ sudo -u bib echo "Running script as user $(whoami)"
Running script as user terdon

$ sudo -u bib sh -c 'echo "Running script as user $(whoami)"'
Running script as user bib
```

So, if you want to run specific commands as a different user, then yes, this is the way to do it. It is just the output of `whoami` that is confusing you.